# is it possible to automate the RMI?

Tags: java, automation, rmi

I was going through the RMI documents and was wondering if it is possible to automate RMI?
For example i have 4 classes
1 interface, 1 implementation class, 1 server class and 1 client class.
Now in order to access an object remotely one has to

1. compile all classes

   ```
   javac class.java
   ```
2. start rmiregistry
3. start server
4. run client

   ```
   java client
   ```

which will display the output.But can I *create, export and bind the server object to rmi registry automatically* when its class object is created? So that the server is ready as long as the object is alive and tha client can start accessing the methods?

I have only 1 class that is a server and it is not accessed by any other classes except for the client, so *there are no security issues* also involved in this.

My prime moto is to execute all the 4 steps listed above in the code itself and make the server class methods accesible to client.No manual execution of `javac`, start `rmiregistry`, start server and java client.

Also is it possible for the client to access the server without any commands like `start rmiregistry`and `start server` being run from the server side if the server uses LocateRegistry.getRegistry() instead of LocateRegisgtry.creareRegistry(1099) ??

Comment: You can do this by ANT script Please go through http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html for basics

Comment: you can use whatever scripting language you want, and ship that script with the rest of the code. Keep in mind depending on what you choose, the user would need to have the runtime environment setup. One of the most common approaches is batch/bash scripts.

Comment: No you can't. You can't write an ANT script that will cause the server to bind itself into the Registry.

Comment: I can have a system dependent shell or batch file for that and invoke that from ANT script

Comment: No you can't. The handwaving about 'system dependent' doesn't change anything. No script or shell or batch file can cause the server to bind itself into the Registry. The server itself can do that, but then you don't need the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're content with having the lifespan of the registry be the same as the lifespan of the server process, the [`LocateRegistry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html) class has `createRegistry(...)` methods which allow you to build an in-process registry easily. All the `rmiregistry` program does is put a tiny little wrapper around a call to `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);`.